# How to execute a shell script from within an .app, and show it in the Terminal?

Tags: macos, shell

My goal is to execute a shell script by double clicking on an OS X .app, and the Terminal to be visible to the user (my script has a CLI GUI).

Any ideas? I've tried [appify](https://gist.github.com/mathiasbynens/674099) but I can't get it to show the Terminal window.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For those interested, I found the following solution which involves using an Apple Script command.

First you need to create a launcher.sh script. 
Use the code below. The many quotes below allow your app to run from a path with spaces.

```
#!/bin/bash
scriptPath=$(dirname "$0")'/yourscript.sh'
osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal" to do script "\"'"$scriptPath"'\""'
```

Use [appify](https://gist.github.com/mathiasbynens/674099) to generate an app bundle.
Type this in the Terminal to do it:

```
appify launcher.sh "Your app name"
```

From Finder,
right-click on your generated app bundle, Show package contents, and paste yourscript.sh into /Contents/MacOS/

Comment: Nicely done. You can simplify the launcher script with ` open -a Terminal "$scriptPath"`